# how to execute a sudo chown command manually

Tags: ssh, cpanel, sudo, shared-hosting, suitecrm

I am trying to install suitecrm on a shared hosting. 
My godaddy hosting has limited SSH, which doesn't allow me to use sudo commands.

Is there any manual/other ways for me to achieve the following permission setting?

```
  sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
```

Answer (score 0):

Webhosting companies usually work using SuPHP, which means that the user PHP is running with is the same that owns the data.

For example, if you login to the hosting account using `userABC` account, all the files will be owned by `userABC`.

In other words, you don't need to change the ownership, it should work fine if you uploaded the file using the account user.

Also, is not possible for a non-root, non-sudo enabled user to execute sudo commands.